# Would this situation be a mongodb server's bug?

Tags: java, mongodb

Today I try to `$set` a DBRef with `$db` to collection.

But server say: "not okForStorage" , so operation is failed.

ps. my `mongod` version is 2.2

```
{
  "ts" : ISODate("2013-01-16T14:05:42.814Z"),
  "op" : "update",
  "ns" : "mydb.coll1",
  "query" : {
    "_id" : NumberLong("928686353793211381")
  },
  "updateobj" : {

    "$set" : {
    "ref" : {
      "$db" : "db2",
      "$ref" : "coll2",
      "$id" : NumberLong("928686353793211381")
      }
    }
  },
  "nscanned" : 1,
  "keyUpdates" : 0,
  "numYield" : 0,
  "lockStats" : {
    "timeLockedMicros" : {
      "r" : NumberLong(0),
      "w" : NumberLong(200)
    },
    "timeAcquiringMicros" : {
      "r" : NumberLong(0),
      "w" : NumberLong(5)
    }
  },
  "exception" : "not okForStorage",
  "exceptionCode" : 12527,
  "millis" : 0,
  "client" : "10.168.89.9",
  "user" : ""
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/database-references/#format), the order of the fields in the DBRef matters; so you'd need to reorder your `ref` object as:

```
"ref" : {
  "$ref" : "coll2",
  "$id" : NumberLong("928686353793211381"),
  "$db" : "db2"
}
```